# How to remove comma from the end of commands list? DiscordJS v14

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to remove the comma from the end of the commands list when i select a category from the dropdown menu, i've tried a few things from help servers but they didnt work, so im resorting to the help from you guys here on stackoverflow.

**IMAGE**
[image]

**COMMAND**

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, ChatInputCommandInteraction, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, StringSelectMenuBuilder, StringSelectMenuOptionBuilder, Client } = require("discord.js");
const botconfig = require("../../botconfig");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("help")
    .setDescription("Sends the command list!"),
  async execute(interaction, client, args) {
    const dirs = fs.readdirSync("./commands");
    const slashCommands = await client.application.commands.fetch();

    const Buttons = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId("left")
        .setLabel("❮")
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
        
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId("right")
        .setLabel("❯")
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
    );

    const embedMsg = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle("__A1's Help Menu__")
      .setDescription(`>>> Prefix: \`${botconfig.defaultPrefix}\`\nVersion: \`${botconfig.version}\`\nCommands: \`${slashCommands.size}\``)
      .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .addFields([
        {
          name: " - **Action**",
          value: " - **Administration**"
        },
        {
          name: " - **Birthday**",
          value: " - **Fun**"
        },
        {
          name: "️ - **Image**",
          value: " - **Level**"
        },
        {
          name: " - **Minigame**",
          value: "⚙️ - **Miscellaneous**"
        },
        {
          name: "️ - **Moderation**",
          value: " - **Ticket**"
        }
      ])
      .setColor("#EE1C25")
      .setFooter({ text: "Navigate through the embeds using the provided menu below.", iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL() })

    let helpMenu = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
      new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId("helpMenu")
        .setMaxValues(1)
        .setMinValues(1)
        .setPlaceholder("Select Command Category")
    );

    fs.readdirSync("./commands").forEach((command) => {
      helpMenu.components[0].addOptions({
        label: `${command}`,
        description: `${command} commands`,
        value: `${command}`,
      });
    });

    // for (const folders of commandFolder) {
    //   helpMenu.components[0].addOptions({
    //     label: `${folders}`,
    //     description: `Command list for ${folders}`,
    //     value: `${folders}`,
    //   });
    // }

    interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embedMsg],
      components: [helpMenu, Buttons],
    });
  },
};
```

**INTERACTIONCREATE**

```
const { Client, ChatInputCommandInteraction, InteractionType, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
  const fs = require("fs");
  
  module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    async execute(interaction, client) {
      if (interaction.isSelectMenu) {
        if (interaction.customId === "helpMenu") {
          const selection = interaction.values[0];
          const commands = fs
            .readdirSync(`./commands/${selection}`)
            .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"))
            .join(" ")
            .split(".js");
  
          function capitalizeFL(str) {
            const capitalized = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
            return capitalized;
          }
  
          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`Command list for ${selection}`)
            .setDescription(`\`\`\`${commands}\`\`\``)
            .setColor("Blurple")
            .addFields({
              name: `Command Count`,
              value: `${commands.length - 1} command(s)`,
            });
  
          await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed],
            ephemeral: true,
          });
        }
      }
    },
  };
```

I tired methods from others in a support discord server, dang near all of them didn't work, then they just stopped answering, and yeah like what da hek mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you test this with an array you can see the issue:

```js
const files = ["test.js", "b.js", "add.js"]

const fileNames = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js")).join(" ").split(".js");

console.log(fileNames);
```

There is an empty string at the end of the array, and if you call `join()` on the array this element is joined too, resulting in an comma at the end. Because you check if the file ends with `.js` you can just remove the 3 characters at the end.

```js
const files = ["test.js", "b.js", "add.js"]

const fileNames = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js")).map((file) => file.slice(0, -3));

console.log(fileNames);
```